# Why does the click event only fire for the first element in this KoGrid template?

Tags: knockout.js, kogrid

I'm trying to bind a click event handler to some anchor tags in a KoGrid. However, the click event only attaches to the first anchor tag. It's not a syntax error because if I switch the order of the tags then the previously non-working second link starts working.

Here is the jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaHFz/12/)

```
<!-- Html -->
<div style="height: 300px; width: 500px" class="gridStyle" data-bind="koGrid: gridOptions"></div>

// Javascript
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Events = ko.observableArray([
        { FirstName: "Jenny", LastName: "Jones" },
        { FirstName: "Henry", LastName: "Howe" }
    ]);

    self.gridOptions = {
        data: self.Events,
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'FirstName' },
            { field: 'LastName' },
            { field: 'ActionField0', displayName: '&nbsp;',
             cellTemplate:
                 '<a href="#" data-bind="click: $userViewModel.save">Save</a> ' +
                 '<a href="#" data-bind="click: $userViewModel.edit">Edit</a>'         
            }
        ],
        autogenerateColumns: false,
        canSelectRows: false,
        showColumnMenu: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        enableColumnResize: false
    };

    self.edit = function() {
        alert("Edit");
    }

    self.save = function() {
        alert("Save");
    }
}

$(function () {
    var peopleViewModel = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(peopleViewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cellTemplate` **requires to have one root level element**. In your case your celltemplate contains two `a` so it just takes the first.

In order to make it work (if you don't want to create two separate columns) just wrap the two anchors in a `div`:

```
cellTemplate:
    '<div>' +
    '<a href="#" data-bind="click: $userViewModel.save">Save</a> ' +
    '<a href="#" data-bind="click: $userViewModel.edit">Edit</a>' +
    '</div>'
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfnUn/).